# Exporting asp grid data to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, grid

I want to export my grid data directly to Excel.

I tried "HtmlTextWriter" and it is allowing me to download the file. But after downloading I cant open the file (Excel throwing error that file is not in correct format.)

I searched and found that I need to first create a XML file and then can export to Excel. Is it so?

Or do I need to first save that file on my server and then download?

Or if I can use any NuGet package like ClosedXML or anyother will help.

Comment: A simple [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) would do. What did the file look like that was generated by the htmltextwriter when opened in notepad?

Comment: It is looking like having tags <table> <span> <td>

Answer (score 0):

try the following code on button click

```
protected void btn_excel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
            work();   // in this function you can bind GridView2

            GridView2.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = GridView2.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView2.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView2.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            GridView2.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: I already tried it. But after downloading excel is throwing error that it is not in correct format.

Comment: then your software has problem. you have to try on different pc.

Comment: I am getting below error. "The file format and extension of 'GridViewExport.xlx' dosen't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, dont't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

If I opens the file I cant see few columns. Also I have my first column as check box. Is it creating a problem?

Comment: Have you tried on other pc. I think your ms office version is conflicting

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to grab ClosedXML from Nuget and then get your data that you want to export into a datatable and then use this code below

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable dt = GetDataTableOrWhatever();
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt,"WorksheetName");
```

Comment: Thanks sounds good. Can you please help me with a bit more code?

Comment: @Palash be careful not to become a [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: I can try, if its related to this question, update your question, otherwise you would need to ask another question

Comment: Not trying to be a help vampire. But tired of trying the ways I can export to eXCEL. Also just FYI my grid is having 1st column as checkbox.

Help Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try the code, and let us know how you get on with it, if you encounter any new issues let us know as this could turn into a remote debugging session